# Phalcon - mock models for unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, phalcon

I am trying to perform a Unit test in my Phalcon app. I have setup the Unit test environment according to the tutorial provided.

What I am trying to do is to mock database adapter only for several functions. I want a mocked DB adapter, and when I call get method I want it to return a known dataset.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am finding unit testing with Phalcon overly difficult.

Not sure the following will answer your question but it seems 10months with out a response is a long time.

What I ended up doing was using mockery like so

```
$aclResultArray = ['role_name' => 'Pre Sale'];

    $aclMock = m::mock('overload:\Model\ModelFolder\ModelName');
    $aclMock->shouldReceive('findFirst')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn((object)$aclResultArray);
```

Hope this helps